# MTOM attachment size limit in WebSphere application server

Tags: java, web, service, websphere, mtom

I have a web service with MTOM enabled that receives binary attachments as part of the message payload from the client facing applications. The service is deployed on WebSphere application server. There is no SOAP message handler in place. However, I happen to notice that attachments with greater than 10 MB in size are being dropped by the server or not processed. Basically WebSphere stores the temporary attachments in "IBMTmpCD"  folder with *.att filename extension. In the logic when the service attempts to grab the input stream from the Data Handler, the File Not found Exception is thrown. As a result the BLOB does not get created that further causes issues.

My question is that is there a Web Service Proxy settings or any other settings that control the MTOM attachment size limit. I am using MTOM annotation with default values on the service implementation. If a client application sends an attachment of size less than 10 MB then all is well; but when any attachment greater than 10 MB seems like is being blocked by the server or not processed. I have also monitored the SOAP message using TCP/IP monitor, the MTOM attachment message is formed correctly as expected.

Also, if I disable MTOM then attachments greater than 10MB is successfully received and processed by the server.

Environment:
Java 7
WebSphere 8.5

Any help on this issue is very much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not aware of any upper limit.  Some front ends limit the size of attachments, and mtom is a mime attachment. If you're passing through some front end http server or load balancer, you might try sending direct to WebSphere and see if anything changes.   There are some jvm properties that limit temp file size and retention, but the defaults are pretty generous.

Comment: com.ibm.ws.websvcs.attachments.sizethreshold jvm property can be set to a higher value to avoid the use of the tempfile, if you have sufficient heap.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried sending directly to the application server still not luck. Following exception is thrown when the time comes to persist the document into the DB.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: IBMTmpCD\Axis203cd95d26a536d35f4a46b659af2beb8b030be35cabe5008.att (The system cannot find the file specified.)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:149)
 at javax.activation.FileDataSource.getInputStream(FileDataSource.java:109)
 at javax.activation.DataHandler.getInputStream(DataHandler.java:250)

Comment: I wonder if there is some permissions error so the file can't be created.  Can you see it on disk using a command prompt?  It should persist until the JVM is restarted.

Comment: I have the folder cleaned up and permissions are 775, still same issue as above. Seeing the exception same as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an issue anymore as per comments below. It's a concurrency issue in the service logic.

Answer (score 0):

10 MB is probably the cluster default file upload size.

If I remember correctly you can override the value in the web.xml Try something like (not sure about these values)

```
<multipart-config>
   <max-file-size>52428800</max-file-size>
   <max-request-size>52428800</max-request-size>
   <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>
```

Comment: Tried but no luck. Could not find anything related to cluster default file upload size. When the message arrives - the FNF exception is thrown when an attempt is made to retrieve the InputStream from DataHandler - to be more specific  DataHandlerExtImpl - one of the axiom implementation classes.

Comment: Found the root cause of the problem. The issue is in the service logic. The request is delegated to managed thread grabbed from the thread pool to avoid client waiting for long time. When the attempt was made to get Input Stream from the DataHandler, it would throw the FNF exception since there is no connection to the client anymore. As soon as I moved the logic to main request thread, mime attachment more than 11MB came through. I wonder if there is a way the managed thread can still maintain the connection with the client application during the stream of binary content.